# Can't send pytorch tensor to cuda

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I create a torch tensor and I want it to go to GPU but it doesn't. This is so broken. What's wrong?

```
def test_model_works_on_gpu():
    with torch.cuda.device(0) as cuda:
        some_random_d_model = 2 ** 9
        five_sentences_of_twenty_words = torch.from_numpy(np.random.random((5, 20, T * d))).float()
        five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask = torch.from_numpy(np.ones((5, 1, 20))).float()
        pytorch_model = make_sentence_model(d_model=some_random_d_model, T_sgnn=T, d_sgnn=d)

        five_sentences_of_twenty_words.to(cuda)
        five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask.to(cuda)
        print(type(five_sentences_of_twenty_words), type(five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask))
        print(five_sentences_of_twenty_words.is_cuda, five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask.is_cuda)
        pytorch_model.to(cuda)
        output_before_match = pytorch_model(five_sentences_of_twenty_words, five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask)

        assert output_before_match.shape == (5, some_random_d_model)
        print(type(output_before_match))
        print(output_before_match.is_cuda, output_before_match.get_device())
```

```
tests/test_model.py:58: RuntimeError

<class 'torch.Tensor'> <class 'torch.Tensor'>
False False
<class 'torch.Tensor'>

>       print(output_before_match.is_cuda, output_before_match.get_device())
E       RuntimeError: get_device is not implemented for tensors with CPU backend
```

Also:

```
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
True
>>> torch.cuda.device_count()
2
```

And:

```
pip freeze | grep -i torch
torch==1.0.0
torchvision==0.2.1
```

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is the following lines:

```
five_sentences_of_twenty_words.to(cuda)
five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask.to(cuda)
```

`.to(device)` only operates in place when applied to **a model**.

When applied to **a tensor**, it must be assigned:

```
five_sentences_of_twenty_words = five_sentences_of_twenty_words.to(cuda)
five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask = five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask.to(cuda)
```

Answer (score 1):

To transfer a "CPU" tensor to "GPU" tensor, simply do:

```
cpuTensor = cpuTensor.cuda()
```

This would take this tensor to default GPU device. If you have multiple of such GPU devices, then you can also pass device_id like this:

```
cpuTensor = cpuTensor.cuda(device=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by doing this:

```
def test_model_works_on_gpu():
    device_id = 0
    with torch.cuda.device(device_id) as cuda:
        some_random_d_model = 2 ** 9
        five_sentences_of_twenty_words = torch.from_numpy(np.random.random((5, 20, T * d))).float()
        five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask = torch.from_numpy(np.ones((5, 1, 20))).float()
        pytorch_model = make_sentence_model(d_model=some_random_d_model, T_sgnn=T, d_sgnn=d)

        five_sentences_of_twenty_words = five_sentences_of_twenty_words.cuda(device_id)
        five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask = five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask.cuda(device_id)
        print(type(five_sentences_of_twenty_words), type(five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask))
        print(five_sentences_of_twenty_words.is_cuda, five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask.is_cuda)
        pytorch_model = pytorch_model.cuda(device_id)
        output_before_match = pytorch_model(five_sentences_of_twenty_words, five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask)

        assert output_before_match.shape == (5, some_random_d_model)
        print(type(output_before_match))
        print(output_before_match.is_cuda, output_before_match.get_device())
        assert output_before_match.is_cuda
        assert five_sentences_of_twenty_words.is_cuda
        assert five_sentences_of_twenty_words_mask.is_cuda
```

I also used the [`add_module` method](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/when-to-use-add-module-function/10534) in my modules.